# Error in content downloading, IIS 7.5 + ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, combres

My web-application has been written in ASP.NET MVC 3 (also we used ASP.NET Sprite & Combres).
It's all right in testing on local IIS 7.5 (and on dev-server of Visual Studio).

But we have an error with content downloading (css and js files) if we use a remote webserver: it becomes when size of content is more then some value (~ 250 KB) and it's aborting of downloading by browser on 36B-value (but is's 200 OK via Firebug).

Initially increasing of cache size of IIS may help, but with increasing of quantity of static files and their size this error returns.

Disabling of Combres/ASP.NET doesn't help.

We meet with the same problem on the same webserver in standard default enter of IIS (it's picture with multilanguage welcome): only part of picture is downloaded.

This error isn't regular: with increasing of Internet speed, the probability of error is decreasing. We have this error on two different webservers.

Comment: When reading this question it seems not related to ASP.NET MVC but rather on how you set up your IIS/webserver.

Comment: I'll bet its the connection timeout in web.config, can you post it up?

Comment: IIS is used with nginx, but unfortunatly we haven't access to options of nginx - it's foreign server.